# Are Tamed Monster Growth Patterns Random?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

Does a tamed monster of a particular type always have the same final "leveling" disposition?

For example, every single Pulse Knight I've tamed so far has been an **Early Learner**. I was hoping to use him further into the game, but with a maximum level of 20 it's not feasible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strategy guide confirms that the type of monster determines their growth pattern and their level cap: if one Pulse Knight is an early learner, they all are.

Comment: There is some deviation on how they'll develop though, right? As in two Pulse Knights can end up with slightly different statistics in the end?

Comment: @Yuck As far as I understand it, growth is deterministic, but you can customize your monsters based on what materials and crystals you use. If you use exactly the same things, they *should* turn out identically.

Comment: Right - looks like there's items that increase all stats, health, strength, and magic. So if you were building a `SEN` type you'd want to try to pump mostly health and strength items while leveling up instead of just using whatever is available.

Comment: From what i have experienced all monsters have slightly different base stats but this is negligable seeing we are talking about 1~5 strength / magic and tops 20 hp.